# Как убрать кнопку загрузки в теге <audio> в браузере Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, аудио

С обновлением браузера Chrome в тег  добавили кнопку загрузки.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Заказчик хочет, чтобы ее не было видно. Есть ли простые способы это сделать?

Или не простые...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По-моему аналогичный [вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41115801/in-chrome-55-prevent-showing-download-button-for-html-5-video) на английском

Решение:

```
video::-internal-media-controls-download-button {
    display:none;
}

video::-webkit-media-controls-enclosure {
    overflow:hidden;
}

video::-webkit-media-controls-panel {
    width: calc(100% + 30px); /* Adjust as needed */
}
```

только видео меняем на аудио.

Answer (score 0):

> Заказчик хочет, чтобы ее не было видно. Есть ли простые способы это сделать?

Конечно. Вставь в тег `<audio>`(`<video>`) атрибут `controlsList="nodownload"` и нет проблем.